# C++ - Copying a file to all sub directories

Tags: c++

I'm trying to create a program for educative purposes which should be able to copy one file (of any extension, the name of the file never changes) inside the same directory of the `.exe` to all the directories inside the main directory.
Thus for example I have:

- Main_Directory
- Program.exe
- file.something
- Directory1
- Directory2
- Directory3

In that situation, the program should copy file.something into directory1, 2 and 3.
Through the use of this code I have access to the absolute path of the `.exe`'s folder:

```
char basePath[255]="";
_fullpath(basePath,argv[0],sizeof(basePath));
```

Ideally, to solve the problem, two function could be made:

First function:

```
Input:
(char[]) The .exe's folder if necessary
Output:
(int) Number of folders inside the .exe's folder.
```

Second function:

```
input:
(int) which folder to pick
(int) total number of folders
(char[]) the .exe's folder if necessary
Output:
(char[]) the name of the folder
```

With those two functions (which should return an array of chars instead of a string as I was forced to use those arrays to make the code work) I'd be able to make a simple loop, changing the destination's folder every time and copying the file to it.

Of course it's just how the problem could be fixed, if a better solution exists, so be it.

One last thing: I'd be really happy if you could add what each block or command does as I'm still learning c++ and I'm currently a beginner.

Comment: boost's directory iterator is great for something like this.

Comment: If you are learning C++, don't cross-tag C unless you specifically *know* how to do it in C or want a compare/contrast. The "natural" solution may be very different.

Comment: AndyG: I'd prefer not to use external resources if it's possible, but if they're simply better then they're welcome.
crashmstr: My apologies, this is my first question on stackoverflow.

Comment: C++ can do this; C++ can do almost anything. But it wouldn't be an experienced programmer's first choice. Unless on Windows, I'd look first at a shell script, then at whichever of Python, Perl, or Ruby comes most naturally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assumptions:

- You write non portable code, making use of non portable function `[_fullpath()`][1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/506720ff.aspx)
- You target windows only
- You work with unicode disabled as you use `_fillpath()` and not `_wfullpath()`
- You do not want to use third party libraries

**How to do it with windows ?**

You could use FindFirstFile() and FindNextFile() to iterate through the directories.  MSDN has a [nice example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365200%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) of how to use them.

Unfortunately `FindFirstFile()` is very basic and limits itself to search entries based on a filename containing wildcards.  As you are looking for directories, it's more tricky:  you'll have to use [`FindFirstFileEx()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364419%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  The parameter called fSearchOp in the function documentation should be `FindExSearchLimitToDirectories`

The data is returned in [WIN32_FIND_DATA](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365740%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) structure where you can read the `cFileName`.  By the way, try to avoid at any cost hard coded length like 255 and prefer well known constants instead (here the windows specific MAX_PATH).

Finally, while you are looping, you may perform the copying either using your own C++ standard based copy function, or using the windows specific [`CopyFile()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363851%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

**Final remarks**

This kind of gymnastics is not at all portable.  If you'd like to use your code on other platforms than windows, you'd have to use a completely different API, for example [dirent.h](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/dirent.h.html) for unix/linux and co.   This is why, for this particular kind of work, a third party library like boost is extremely useful. If you have time, look here for a [directory iteration](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/filesystem/v3/doc/tutorial.html) tutorial with boost and compare with the windows based code.

Comment: :Thank you for your answer, it's really useful!
However,let's assume the executable is inside the folder a\b\c, if i set the first variable required as "a\b\c", then it'll pick files from the a\b folder. However, if i input anything like a\b\c\*.* the first file is a dot, while if i input a\b\c\* then it'll print out weird stuff.
What am i supposed to give as input?

Comment: I think i fixed it:
I've put three folders inside the exe's folder, they're named x,y,z. If i search for the path 'a\b\c\*.' multiple times (assuming the program is inside a\b\c) then outputs will be: . .. x y z z z z z. The result are enough to successfully make the program work!
However i wonder if the output would be "prettier" or if the call just works like that...

*edit*
using a\b\c\*.? also lists folders with dots in it.
However, it doesn't list folders _ending_ with a dot. In that case i'd need to use \*.* but then it'd list all files alike.

Comment: Just finished making the program, it works wonderfully!
Thank you for your answer, it helped me enough to finish it! ^^